# no grid lines are showing in cinema 4d r23 in windows 10?

Tags: animation, 3d, modeling, cinema-4d

I have recently installed the cinema 4d r23 but after launching the program I saw that there was not grid lines and whole area was filled with black.

What should be the fix or should I download another edition?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your graphics card drivers

Also, check if your laptop has another graphic chip, if so, try disabling it from the BIOS, it might be the cause of the problem.